# How to Show Two textBox control content in third one using concatenating in WPF only in xaml binding no viewmodel code & code behind code

Tags: c#, wpf

How to Show Two textBox control content  in third one using concatenating in WPF only in xaml binding no viewmodel code & code behind code.

Comment: Maybe in a TextBlock?
Linking from two sources is still possible.
But to do back-binding from target to two sources without logic .....
How do you imagine it?
Let's say you have the value "1234567".
How can I split it into two sources?

Comment: TextBox1= " Test1",TextBox2="test2" then textBox3="Test1 Test2".

Comment: This should be done using xaml code only

Comment: I am writing again.
The problem is not getting one text from two texts (contact).
But how to do the back return of one text by anchor in two texts (Split).
If you don't need to edit the connected text, then it's enough to use a TextBlock with nested Runs.

Comment: If you need to edit the concated text, then you will definitely have to apply a multi converter in binding with two texts. And the logic of concatenate and splitting will be in this converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=txt1}"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=txt2}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Where the ElementName property is the Name of your TextBoxes.

If you do not want a space between the runs, then put them on the same line like this.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=txt1}"/><Run Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=txt2}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry just re-read the question, and believe you want the output to be in another TextBox. TextBoxes do not support the Run object so you have to approach this with a MultiBinding.

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}">
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="txt1" />
            <Binding Path="Text" ElementName="txt2" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This binding will not work in the opposite direction.
Try changing the value in the resulting TextBox and you will see that there will be no changes in the source TextBoxes .
And I asked TC to explain this logic of reverse assignment by binding.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Thomas,the above solution is working.